# Событие при innerText в js

Tags: javascript

Есть вот такой кусок кода. Хочу отловить событие изменения innerText

```
    content.querySelector('.hotel-rating').onchange = function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    };
    console.dir(content.querySelector('.hotel-rating'));

    content.querySelector('.hotel-name').innerText = data.name;
    content.querySelector('.hotel-stars').innerText = data.stars;
    content.querySelector('.hotel-price').innerText = data.price;
    content.querySelector('.hotel-rating').innerText = data.rating;
```

Но я так понял, что событие `onchange`  мне в этом не поможет....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал через прослушивание события

```
content.querySelector('.hotel-rating').addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
      console.log(1);
});
```

Но мне кажется, что есть вариант и попроще...